# Laravel CSRF Tokens on Angular Form

Tags: angular, laravel

I'm creating an application with `Angular` as frontend and `Laravel` framework for my backend.
How do you create a `@csrf` input on a frontend Angular form for a `POST` ajax request? How do you implement it?

Comment: I don't know much about `Laravel` but i don't think you need to send `csrf token` with `angular`. As you will be sending the `bearer token` with every request.

Answer (score 0):

You neet to pass a 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token with every your request.
Also enable the CSRF filter on Laravel.

Example:

```
<script>angular.module("App").constant("CSRF_TOKEN", '{!! csrf_token() !!}');</script>
```

Then in your module methods it can be injected when needed:

```
app.factory("FooService", function($http, CSRF_TOKEN) {
    console.log(CSRF_TOKEN);
};
```